# remove only consecutive special characters but keep consecutive [a-zA-Z0-9] and single characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How can I remove multiple consecutive occurrences of *all* the special characters in a string?

I can get the code like:

```
re.sub('\.\.+',' ',string)
re.sub('@@+',' ',string)
re.sub('\s\s+',' ',string)
```

for individual and in best case, use a loop for all the characters in a list like:

```
from string import punctuation

for i in punctuation:
    to = ('\\' + i + '\\' + i + '+')
    string = re.sub(to, ' ', string)
```

but I'm sure there is an effective method too.

I tried:

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ' ', '\n\n.AAA.x.@@+*@#=..xx000..x..\t.x..\nx*+Y.')
```

but it removes all the special characters except one preceded by alphabets.

string can have different consecutive special characters like `99@aaaa*!@#$.` but not same like `++--...`.

Comment: `re.sub(r'([^\w\s])\1+',' ',text)` or `re.sub(r'(\W)\1+',' ',text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern to match all non-alphanumeric characters in Python is `[\W_]`.

So, all you need is to wrap the pattern with a capturing group and add `\1+` after it to match 2 or more consecutive occurrences of the same non-alphanumeric characters:

```
text = re.sub(r'([\W_])\1+',' ',text)
```

In Python 3.x, if you wish to make the pattern ASCII aware only, use the `re.A` or `re.ASCII` flag:

```
text = re.sub(r'([\W_])\1+',' ',text, flags=re.A)
```

Mind the use of the `r` prefix that defines a raw string literal (so that you do not have to escape `\` char).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ihzHsg/1). See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cclOYZ):

```
import re
text = "\n\n.AAA.x.@@+*@#=..xx000..x..\t.x..\nx*+Y."
print(re.sub(r'([\W_])\1+',' ',text))
```

Output:

```
 .AAA.x. +*@#= xx000 x  .x 
x*+Y.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. Why is there an ```_``` inside ```[ ]``` though?

Comment: @Deshwal To match `\W` and `_`. `\W` matches any char but a letter, digit and `_`. `_` is not alphanumeric, so you need to "combine" it with `\W`, hence, the usage of the character class.

Comment: oh!okay. that I knew but thought there might be some special about _ like ^ in [^]